# is escaping eval variables safe enough?

Tags: php, eval

Is escaping eval variables safe enough from security point of view. For e.g.

```
$path = "a";    //sample value; is generated dynamically
$var = "phpinfo()";     //sample attack value; is generated dynamically
eval("\$struct$path = \$var;");
```

this seems to be working safely to me. Although there seems to be no reason of using the code in the first place, now that it is in, it cannot be removed without a reason.

Is there any way (any value for $var or $path) that can break this eval or is it that i am simply worrying too much :-) and this is a safe case???

Comment: Why and how should any value for $var break the eval? (Maybe c/p-mistake?)

Comment: you shouldn't use eval at all, in my opinion, you can do everything without it. No Idea what you would need it for.

Comment: @Martin - sorry c/p errror.. fixed now..
@xXX - try reading the question.. i have mentioned that this is a legacy system.. just shouting eval is bad wont change peoples mind.. give me an example here... i am as against eval as anybody else, but in a legacy codebase, changes need reasons..

Comment: @pinaki eval is crap. Why is that not reason enough to fix this? Especially when a rewrite is so easy: `$varname = $struct.$path; $$varname = $var`

Comment: @pekka organizational policies is what i am told. saying something crap is not enough until u can prove it..

Comment: @pinaki so bad practices can be removed only when they are *proven* bad? That sounds *horribly* ineffective, even dangerous, especially at this level of coding. Don't they trust their programmers at all?

Comment: @pekka that's moving away from the point.. i am not sure anyone in this world trusts programmers (not even programmers trust programmers as such).. ;-).. but seriously, i know why eval is bad and everything but bad practices are seldom part of code change in any organization.. if you prove it is bad, it is a different issue altogther...

Comment: @pinaki if you need to build a watertight case - with proof of concept and everything - to change the above line to the line I quote (if I'm correct in that this would be the replacement) then time is being wasted. I'm sure you have your reasons and it could well be that I don't understand the situation, but to me, it sounds really dumb to have to *prove* this is bad.

Comment: @pekka - well i can only say that you have seen nothing bad in the world yet ;-).. try this http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Slaves-to-The-Process.aspx as an example... even if i agree with you that it is dumb, that doesnt really change anything... to make a change i need reasons, and if you cannot give me that then i can be happy with my accepted answer for now..

Comment: @pinaki I see your point, but I can only reiterate that this practice is really  dangerous and needs changing. ("dumb", I agree,  is present in most companies across the world - no big deal :)  There may be security holes that are yet unknown, or nobody of us here managed to see, that could allow execution of harmful code through this eval() statement. Maybe only in a later version of PHP! *eval is not needed here, and opens a potential attack vector*. That alone should be all the reason needed to get rid of it, proof or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where `$path` is coming from.
This value breaks it:

```
=0;unlink('/important/file');//
```

Comment: +1. excellent.. is there any case in which $var can break it?

Comment: Not in this eval, the $ is prefixed with a \. But if $structa should be a number (e.g. an ID for MySQL), and you're entering a string like `'`, then it will be broken on that.

Comment: cool.. so i take it that this is a safe case of eval at work since it turned out $path is calculated and not from user inputs.. accepting urs as the correct answer... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what your eval code is actually supposed to do. But if it's just about a dynamic varname how about something like that:

```
extract(array("\$struct$path", "\$var"));
```

Faster.

Answer (score -2):

You could need **eval** to implement a plugin system with hooks... But you should never execute dynamic content with it (like phpinfo).